# Is there any way to create a telegram payment bot without any payment provided using only tron API

Tags: python, tron

Here is my question; I have a telegram bot which is store bot and I want to receive payments with USDT but without using any payment provider I want to bot must be able to check tron api and confirm payments. I have a basic python knowledge and using gpt to help. Is it possible to do?

I created the bot added my product information but I want to create a payment bot and its not important to this bot is seperate or included in my code.